# fabric.js lockUniScaling on fabric.Image.fromURL

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I load an image with fabric.js (http://fabricjs.com), but I can't get the 'lockUniScaling' working on my element.

This works:

```
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({ width: 50, height: 50, fill: '#77f', top: 100, left: 100 }));
canvas.item(0).lockUniScaling = true;
```

How can I get the 'lockUniScale' to this element?

```
fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.domain.com/image.png', function(obj) {
    canvas.add(obj.scale(1).rotate(0).set({ left: 100, top: 100 }));
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
```

If I add some other elements I can grab them by using item(1), item(2),... but I can't get the image-element.

Any hints?

Comment: Why can't you do `obj.lockUniScaling = true` in a callback?

Comment: True, thx!

fabric.Image.fromURL('http://www.donain.com/image.png', function(qrcode) {
 qrcode.lockUniScaling = true;
    canvas.add(qrcode.scale(1).rotate(0).set({ left: 100, top: 100 }));
    canvas.renderAll();
  });

works well!